# Is there any way to resolved the network error issues in android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

While uploading files using react-native-document-picker with form-data post api.I have got this Network request failed error in android while in iOS it is working perfectly.Also in android I am getting this error sometimes but sometimes it worked.

```
const selectDocumentsFileSign = async () => {
    try {
        const images = await DocumentPicker.pickSingle({
            type: [DocumentPicker.types.images, DocumentPicker.types.pdf],
        });
        setLoading(true);
        const formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append('image', {
            uri: images.uri,
            type: images.type,
            name: images.name,
        });

        let res = await fetch(Constants.baseUrl + '/image/single-image', {
            method: 'post',
            body: formdata,
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
        });
        let responseJson = await res.json();
        console.log('responseJson', responseJson);
        if (responseJson.success) {
            setLoading(false);
            ShowAlert(responseJson?.message);
            setsignature(responseJson?.data)

        } catch (err) {
            if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
                else {
                    ShowAlert('Network request failed upload again');
                    setLoading(false);
                    throw err;
                }
            }
```

Fix the issues I am facing with android build only.